# How to logout in a android app in background?

Tags: android, session, background, android-activity, logout

I have researched and I found a lot of sollutions how to logout. The big problem is when I´m in background... if I use the setFlags it brings my sollution to the top and if I was doing something else in my device it will come back to foreground.

That´s my sollution and it work fine, but how I do this in background?

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: how is logging out related to starting an activity? this is highly unclear

Comment: How to log out is related totally to how you are logged in.  What does it mean in your app to be "logged in"?

Comment: I can access certain activities when I´m logged in and I can´t access them anymore when I´m logged out. Basicly I have this timer and it´s renewed when I make some move if I have inativity I log out automactly by finishing all other activities and backing to Login activity. I can´t just finish() it because the user can use the back button to go back and access the logged in activities. this sollution that I present work fine in foreground. but when I´m in background and the session expired it brings the app for foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find a way to do that using one sollution that I find here on stack.
I create a broadcast message and when I open the activity I check if the logout message is broadcaster and I finish the activity.

Comment: Add a link for the solution.  So that everyone could get solution for this!